what is the history of applied mathematics?
I am researching the history of applied mathematics and its evolution as a separate academic field. My challenge lies in understanding how it began—who first used mathematics for practical purposes, and in what contexts. I want to trace its development from the ancient civilizations, where early forms of applied mathematics appeared in agriculture, astronomy, and engineering, through to the Renaissance when mathematics played a key role in scientific advancements.
Additionally, I am trying to understand when applied mathematics became recognized as an independent field of study in academic institutions, particularly during the 20th century when universities began offering dedicated programs. The societal and historical contexts are critical, as they influenced the growth and transformation of this field in response to industrial needs, warfare, and scientific progress.
I am looking for sources and information that provide an in-depth look at the historical milestones, as well as the social influences that shaped the development of applied mathematics into a distinct academic discipline.

June Barrow-Green and Reinhard Siegmund-Schultze "The History of Applied Mathematics" In Princeton companion to applied mathematics. Higham, N. J., Dennis, M. R., Glendinning, P., Martin, P. A., Santosa, F., & Tanner, J. (Eds.) (2015) Princeton University Press. pp. 55-79.

Applied mathematics was not considered a separate discipline until 20th century. So its history is just an inseparable part of the history of mathematics. It was practiced by the same people and published in the same journals. The oldest existing math journals are called Journal fur die reine und angewandte Mathematik, and Journal de mathematiques pures et appliquees.

Related When were the concepts of pure and applied Mathematics introduced?
